# I have a question regarding istio rate limit

Tags: istio, rate-limiting

What does the "validDuration", "MaxAmount" parameter mean when using the FIXED_WINDOW algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand from the [istio github repository](https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/mixer/adapter/redisquota) about redis quota, there is no difference in validDuration and MaxAmount in rolling_window and fixed_window. The difference I found is [there](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/fa0cd6ff68c80893fdcf9b2d62d6427361907993/mixer/adapter/redisquota/config/config.proto#L97-L99) and it´s about bucket duration.

> The `bucketDuration` will be ignored if `rateLimitAlgorithm` is `FIXED_WINDOW`

And from [documentation](https://istio.io/v0.8/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/adapters/redisquota/#Params.QuotaAlgorithm)

> FIXED_WINDOW -> The fixed window approach can allow 2x peak specified rate, whereas the rolling-window doesn’t.
>
> ROLLING_WINDOW -> The rolling window algorithm’s additional precision comes at the cost of increased redis resource usage.

Take a look at redisquota code about [max_amount](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/mixer/adapter/redisquota/redisquota.go#L128-L131) and [validDuration](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/mixer/adapter/redisquota/redisquota.go#L109-L112).

So i think the answer for your question is, Quoted from the older [docs](https://istio.io/v0.2/docs/reference/config/mixer/adapters/memquota.html) and above github repository [code](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/2e838e40f37235399acde3052b77a410b0ab4c02/mixer/adapter/redisquota/config/adapter.redisquota.config.pb.html#L153-L170):

> maxAmount  -> int64    -> The upper limit for this quota.
>
> validDuration  -> Duration -> The amount of time allocated quota remains valid before it is automatically released. This is only meaningful for rate limit quotas, otherwise the value must be zero.

Hope you find this useful.